# what does "nightclub gear" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

There is a conversation, see below

> A: Maybe you've got too many clothes. But if you're not going to wash them, what are you going to wear?
>
> B: I've still got my nightclub gear I used to wear as a student – will that do?

what does "nightclub gear" mean ?

Answer (score 2):

If you think of one of the ordinary definitions of *gear*:

> [**gear**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gear) (n): 2. Equipment or apparatus that is used for a particular purpose.

Then the informal meaning of "clothing for a particular purpose" (as well as any number of variations on the same theme) should be easy to understand.  In this case it's "clothing used for going out to nightclubs".

Comment: so, it's similar to dress code?

Comment: @user2680731   No, a "dress code" is the clothing the establishment requires you to wear -- for example, a fancy restaurant might require men to wear a coat and a tie.  "X gear" would be the clothing **you** choose to wear to an establishment of type X.  It would probably be informal and not any standard requirement.